# Mysql NOT IN ()

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql select query with NOT IN function, simplified example below:

```
SELECT 
  tbl1.some_field, 
  tbl1.tested_value,
  tbl2.another_field,
  tbl2.condition
FROM table1 tbl1
LEFT JOIN table2 tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.foreign_key
WHERE tbl1.tested_value NOT IN (tbl2.condition)
```

Values in column tbl1.tested_value are integers (example: 1167)

In column tbl2.condition (varchar (200)) on each row there is a string of numbers delimited by comma (example: 1101,1134,1167).

It seems that when the function NOT IN is performed, in the brackets the retured string is parsed as '1101,1134,1167' as opposed to '1101','1134','1167', resulting in erroneous output.

Any suggestions on how to solve this by either modifying the query or the way the excluded values are stored in column tbl2.condition?

Comment: If you're taking it from a *string of numbers delimited in commas* from a VARCHAR(200) column, it **is** a string of numbers delimited in commas. What else would you expect it to be? How does a VARCHAR(200) column magically turn into a list of integers separated by commas in an IN statement? (And IN is not a function. It's a statement, and it's expected to be an actual list of values or a result set from a SELECT. The parentheses around it indicate the start and end of that list or SELECT statement - IOW, the items in the list.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Would you care to suggest a way in handling the string in such a way so the NOT IN statement returns the correct results? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Stop storing the values in a VARCHAR(200) and put them in a properly normalized database, and then you can use a SELECT to return a proper list of numbers in the NOT IN clause.

Comment: Ken, I get that, but this is not a db i can modify. I am seeking guidance as to what can be done (if anything!) in the context of the situation. I can only modify the query or the way the string is compiled in the varchar column...

Comment: If you cannot or will not normalise your schema then the question doesn't really pertain to an RDBMS. That said, there are functions like FIND_IN_SET() that can help with what you're after

Comment: Thank you for your comments I have resolved my problem by creating a new table and stored the values in a normalised manner.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
SELECT 
tbl1.some_field, 
tbl1.tested_value,
tbl2.another_field,
tbl2.condition
FROM table1 tbl1
LEFT JOIN table2 tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.foreign_key
WHERE tbl1.tested_value NOT IN (select distinct(t2.condition)
                                from table1 t1
                                left JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.foreign_key)
```